# Convert quarterly dataframe to monthly and fill missing values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a quarterly dataframe like this:

```
        date      gdp  rate
0   2003/3/1   523.82   0.1
1   2003/6/1  1172.83   0.2
2   2003/9/1  1882.48   0.4
3  2003/12/1  3585.72   0.1
4   2004/3/1   706.77   0.2
```

I want to fill missing months and back fill `gdp` and `rate` for each month, and get a dataframe like this:

```
       date      gdp  rate
0   2003-03   523.82   0.1
1   2003-04  1172.83   0.2
2   2003-05  1172.83   0.2
3   2003-06  1172.83   0.2
4   2003-07  1882.48   0.4
5   2003-08  1882.48   0.4
6   2003-09  1882.48   0.4
7   2003-10  3585.72   0.1
8   2003-11  3585.72   0.1
9   2003-12  3585.72   0.1
10  2004-01   706.77   0.2
11  2004-02   706.77   0.2
12  2004-03   706.77   0.2
```

How can I do that in Pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is create `DatetimeIndex`, then use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) with `method='bfill'` and `MS` for start of month and last convert to periods by [`DataFrame.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_period.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['date'], ascending=[True])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

df = df.asfreq('MS', method='bfill').to_period('M').reset_index()
print (df)
       date      gdp  rate
0   2003-03   523.82   0.1
1   2003-04  1172.83   0.2
2   2003-05  1172.83   0.2
3   2003-06  1172.83   0.2
4   2003-07  1882.48   0.4
5   2003-08  1882.48   0.4
6   2003-09  1882.48   0.4
7   2003-10  3585.72   0.1
8   2003-11  3585.72   0.1
9   2003-12  3585.72   0.1
10  2004-01   706.77   0.2
11  2004-02   706.77   0.2
12  2004-03   706.77   0.2
```

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing. Just wondering if you have figured out the question I sent you yesterday by email.

Comment: No problem. I should have sent u by `gmail`, you can run the code, the chinese and english version data get different results, i don't where i get wrong.

Comment: @ahbon - email was sent now.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('M')
# df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
df = df.sort_values(by=['date'], ascending=[True])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

df = df.resample('M').bfill().reset_index()
print(df)
```

**output:**

```
       date      gdp  rate
0   2003-03   523.82   0.1
1   2003-04  1172.83   0.2
2   2003-05  1172.83   0.2
3   2003-06  1172.83   0.2
4   2003-07  1882.48   0.4
5   2003-08  1882.48   0.4
6   2003-09  1882.48   0.4
7   2003-10  3585.72   0.1
8   2003-11  3585.72   0.1
9   2003-12  3585.72   0.1
10  2004-01   706.77   0.2
11  2004-02   706.77   0.2
12  2004-03   706.77   0.2
```